# How to go about medical literature review?

Tags: research

Basically, I am relatively new to research (though I do know the gist of it all but doing it is a bit different than knowing.) in an institute that focuses on research much later, however, I wish to start at least writing a medical stand-alone literature review. I do know it isn't as celebrated as a study-research paper, however, being an independent medical student, with close to no funds, does not allow much liberty, thus to slitter into the research world, this is my baby step.

I have the following questions:

What is the minimum number of references, should one review have?*

What is the minimum word limit to literature review?*

What other aspects, I should keep in mind before approaching it? Like what are the common mistakes that beginners tend to make when writing a literature review?

*I know it varies from paper to paper but what is the general consensus on the minimum number that is appreciated?

To put it simply, the general idea of the research is that a certain environmental factor is further contributing to stunted growth.

If you could help me out that would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. The number of references is an interesting question which can have different answers depending upon the medical subject you are covering and amount of literature available. As for word limits, I am not aware of any. Have you found anything in your search for that information? As for *"what other aspects..."*, that sort of question is very open ended and open to opinion which is off-topic here unfortunately. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this.

Comment: Are you looking at any specific areas of the Medical Sciences?